# Back to top button: hide or keep being displayed (JS)

Tags: javascript, php, css

I have a line at the bottom of certain of my PHP pages:

```
<p>
    <a href="#gototop" title="Start of page">
        <img src="img/toparrow.png" class="icons" border="0" />
    </a>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="biografie_de.php" title="back">
        <img src="img/leftarrow.png" class="icons" border="0" />
    </a>
</p>
```

The line should be displayed as a default (for those who don't have JS enabled).

If the user has scrolled because there is enough text on the page, the line with the back to top button (the button is set in the .css file) should be visible.

However, if the user hasn't scrolled down because he has a big screen/high resolution, the entire part

```
<p>
    <a href="#gototop" title="Start of page">
        <img src="img/toparrow.png" class="icons" border="0" />
    </a>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="biografie_de.php" title="back">
        <img src="img/leftarrow.png" class="icons" border="0" />
    </a>
</p>
```

should be hidden. How can I hide it?

Please help me as this is the last problem of my website I've been tweaking for many days.

The problem is I don't know JS at all and can only paste code.
I've already tried some Google results that work per se, but not with my layout and use of CSS and PHP etc.

I tried some Google results, but could not implement them to my page.

Comment: so from what I can understand, if you a user has not scroll, you do not want the back to top button to be shown?

Comment: @KickButtowski Yes. If the content does not fit in the content div and there is a scroll bar, there should be a back to top icon. If there is no scroll bar because there is nothing to scroll, there should not be an icon...it should be hidden. Ken's solution works, but not for all of my pages. e.g.  www.seelenpuls.at/update11/fotografie_en.php should display the back to top for a solution of 1920x1080 (desktop), but does not. Moreover, www.seelenpuls.at/update11/poesie_gedicht30_de.php does not have the back top top either. (when viewing with a resolution of 1920x1080).

18 hours ago

Answer (score 1):

You may check whether the element is in the viewport (When an element is in the viewport, it appears in the visible part of the screen.)

A standard function to check is

```
function isInViewport(element) {
    const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
}
```

So , for your case,

```
<script>
function isInViewport(element) {
    const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
}

</script>
<html>
TEST<br>
TEST<br>
TEST<br>
TEST<br>
TEST<br>
TEST<br>
TEST<br>
TEST<br>
TEST<br>
TEST<br>
TEST<br>
TEST<br>
TEST<br>
TEST<br>
TEST<br>
TEST<br>


<div id="gototopmark">
<p><a href="#gototop" title="Start of page"><img src="img/toparrow.png" class="icons" border="0"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="biografie_de.php" title="back"><img src="img/leftarrow.png" class="icons" border="0"></a>   
</div>

<script>

const box = document.querySelector('#gototopmark');

if (isInViewport(box)){
  box.style.display='none';
}else{
  box.style.display='block';
}

</script>
```

Note:

1. First, we enclose the part which you want to show/hide into DIV tags with ID known as 'gototopmark'
2. the JS at the bottom will check whether this DIV is visible when the page is loaded , and do the thing you want (hide / show the element)

Comment: Ken, thank you! However, your solution does not work for all of my pages.. 

Is there a workaround that does not use the viewport, but "user has scrolled x pixels? If you have to scroll only a bit the "back to top" is hidden although it should not. Moreover, the photo gallery does not work at all (I use include to include the photos and Lightbox.

e.g. https://www.seelenpuls.at/update11/fotografie_en.php should display the back to top for a solution of 1920x1080 (desktop), but does not. 
https://www.seelenpuls.at/update11/poesie_gedicht30_de.php does not have the back top top either.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Ok, thanks. Is it possible to tag or contact Ken directly (PM, DM)? I can tag you, but not him.

Comment: @LeanderRednael, please create a new question post for that so that we can give you the answer separately